# Consulta sobre base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, api, mongodb

Tengo una duda que necesito sacarme. Tengo que realizar un proyecto con .Net (una aplicación para escritorio con C#). La misma debe conectarse a una API. Pero aquí va mi duda, también debe poder trabajar de manera 'offline', es decir que cuando no tenga conexión con Internet para comunicarse con la API, debería de poder trabajar de manera local hasta reanudar la conexión y actualizar la información mediante la API. No sé si esto es posible. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

necesitarías crear una bd intermedia que este alojada en el servidor de la red local de la aplicación de escritorio, y luego un servicio que se encargue de llevar los datos de la bd intermedia al API.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar la data en el browser, usando por ejemplo:

- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) : es sólo un conjunto de llaves y valores. Fácil de usar y casi sin curva de aprendizaje, pero algo limitada como solución para datos estructurados. Para almacenar una estructura con varios campos tienes que guardarlos con JSON.stringify y recuperarlos con JSON.parse.
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB) : tiene una curva de aprendizaje más pronunciada pero permite realizar operaciones más complejas. Hay wrappers como [dexie](http://dexie.org/) y [db.js](http://aaronpowell.github.io/db.js/) que simplifican su uso.
- [Web SQL](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) : **(semi descontinuada)** proporciona una base de datos relacional, básicamente una implementación de SQLite en el browser. A esta altura creo que sólo Chrome y Safari la soportan y **[está siendo deprecada](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated)**.

Lo importante es que manejes el cambio en el estado de la conexión para saber si el usuario está offline (guardas localmente) y cuando pasa a online (sincronizas lo que se almacenó localmente hacia el API).

Por ejemplo puedes comprobar el valor de `navigator.onLine`

```
function persist(...argumentos...) {
  if(navigator.onLine) {
    // guardas mediante el API
  } else {
    // guardas localmente en el browser
  }
}
```

Pero vas a necesitar detectar el cambio de estado para gatillar la sincronización de lo que has guardado mientras estuvo offline:

```
window.addEventListener(‘online’, function(event){
    // sincronizas el local con el API
});
```

Puedes guiarte [por este artículo](https://medium.com/@MateMarschalko/online-and-offline-events-with-javascript-d424bec8f43)